# What to do about [parameter-optimization] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-excerpt

There is a tag [parameter-optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parameter-optimization)×154, without tag wiki or excerpt. It seems to be used mainly for things like maximum likelihood, which has its own tag, further optimization used in estimation is covered by the tag [optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)×1263.  Maybe we should declare `[parameter-optimization]` as a synonym of `[optimization]`? Otherwise it needs a wiki.

Comment: +1. Looks like it should be a synonym.

Comment: If there is no dissent w/i a week or so, ping me & I'll create the synonym.

Comment: This can probably go ahead now @gung.

Comment: I have made p-o a synonym of o, & merged them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems really obvious.  I have made `[parameter-optimization]` a synonym of `[optimization]`, and I merged them.